# Multiple readers found. Cannot determine which to use, specify a name

Tags: c#

Возникает исключение "Multiple readers found. Cannot determine which to use, specify a name" при подключении датчика. Использую датчик ACR1252U-M1. Не могу понять проблема в самом датчике?

```
 private async void GetDevices()
    {
        try
        {
            reader = await CardReader.FindAsync();
            if (reader == null)
            {
                PopupMessage("No Readers Found");
                return;
            }

            reader.CardAdded += CardAdded;
            reader.CardRemoved += CardRemoved;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PopupMessage("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что такое `CardReader.FindAsync`? Какая-то сторонняя библиотека?

Comment: Библиотека для работы со считывателями карт Mifare 
библиотека так и называется "Mifare"

Comment: Код, скорее всего, закрытый? Попробуйте написать разработчикам. Вопрос очень узкий.